# Strictly speaking, what can you do safely with a delegate on multiple threads?

Tags: .net, thread-safety

According to the [System.MulticastDelegate documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx):

> #### Thread Safety
>
> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

The same statement exists in the documentation for System.Delegate.

Now, delegates have an immutable API, but as Eric Lippert explains ["it is a fallacy to believe that just because a data structure does not admit any way for *you* change its contents, its implementation must be threadsafe!"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different.aspx)

Some mechanisms for creating new delegates from existing delegates are static methods: `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove`. So it sounds like these are thread-safe. Given multi-cast delegates A, B and C, I can safely combine A and B to make D on one thread while combining B and C to make E on another.

But invoking a delegate is not a static method. Does that mean that technically my code might break if I share a delegate between threads and invoke it on both, or if I invoke a delegate on one thread while combining it with another on a different thread? Could a standards-conforming implementation of `MulticastDelegate` result in undefined behaviour in such a scenario? Is the delegate returned by `Combine` or `Remove` guaranteed not to share any hidden mutable state with any other delegate?

Note that I'm asking about what the standard *guarantees*, not the current behaviour of C# compilers and CIL JIT compilers. By experimentation, I can determine that this does indeed *appear* to be safe using each of .NET and Mono on the architectures available to me, but I can't see what specifies or guarantees this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

delegates have an immutable interface but are being mutated internally. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524338/122718) to see an example of what might be going on (the answer is not threading-related - it just shows mutation).

**Strictly speaking** you are not even guaranteed to be able to invoke the delegate concurrently. But as a huge part of existing code including the BCL itself relies on this guarantee **it is safe to assume read-only thread-safety**.

**Thread safety in the presence of write cannot be assumed as easily**. I don't know the answer here. The spec does not say anything about threading. It might not be possible to change values of the delegate but they might be perceived as being changed under the influence of threading. Who knows. We are speaking strictly, after all :)

Answer (score 0):

While I can't find any implementation constraints, I believe this is implied.

See section 14.5.10.3 in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf

"The method and object to which a delegate refers are determined when the delegate is instantiated and then remain constant for the entire lifetime of the delegate. In other words, it is not possible to change the target method or object of a delegate once it has been created. [Note: Remember, when two delegates are combined or one is removed from another, a new delegate results; no existing delegate has its content changed. end note]"

While an implementor could intentionally make this misbehave, I can't imagine what would drive such a decision.