# Can delegates cause a memory leak? GC.TotalMemory(true) seems to indicate so

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, delegates, garbage-collection

**Code**

```
using System;
internal static class Test
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Start point", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            Action simpleDelegate = SimpleDelegate;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Simple delegate created", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            Action simpleCombinedDelegate = simpleDelegate + simpleDelegate + simpleDelegate;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Simple combined delegate created", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            byte[] bigManagedResource = new byte[100000000];
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Big managed resource created", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            Action bigManagedResourceDelegate = bigManagedResource.BigManagedResourceDelegate;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Big managed resource delegate created", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            Action bigCombinedDelegate = simpleCombinedDelegate + bigManagedResourceDelegate;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Big combined delegate created", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            GC.KeepAlive(bigManagedResource);
            bigManagedResource = null;
            GC.KeepAlive(bigManagedResourceDelegate);
            bigManagedResourceDelegate = null;
            GC.KeepAlive(bigCombinedDelegate);
            bigCombinedDelegate = null;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Big managed resource, big managed resource delegate and big combined delegate removed, but memory not freed", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            GC.KeepAlive(simpleCombinedDelegate);
            simpleCombinedDelegate = null;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Simple combined delegate removed, memory freed, at last", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            GC.KeepAlive(simpleDelegate);
            simpleDelegate = null;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}: Simple delegate removed", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    private static void SimpleDelegate() { }
    private static void BigManagedResourceDelegate(this byte[] array) { }
}
```

**Output**

```
GC.TotalMemory(true)
    105776: Start point
    191264: Simple delegate created
    191328: Simple combined delegate created
 100191344: Big managed resource created
 100191780: Big managed resource delegate created
 100191812: Big combined delegate created
 100191780: Big managed resource, big managed resource delegate and big combined delegate removed, but memory not freed
    191668: Simple combined delegate removed, memory freed, at last
    191636: Simple delegate removed
```

Comment: Thanks for the executable repro, btw!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Interesting case. Here is the solution:

[image]

Combining delegates is **observationally pure**: It looks like delegates are immutable to the outside. But **internally, existing delegates are being modified**. They share, under certain conditions, the same `_invocationList` for performance reasons (optimizing for the scenario that a few delegates are hooked up to the same event). Unfortunately, the `_invocationList` for the `simpleCombinedDelegate` references the `bigMgdResDelegate` which causes the memory to be kept alive.

Comment: Excellent answer with images and everything.

Comment: Wow, that's surprising! But is it genuine mutation, or a clever local optimization? Perhaps the compiler/JIT looks ahead in the method and create a pre-populated 4-element array once before creating the first delegate?

Comment: @Weeble, not sure what you mean regarding JIT-optimization but the JIT is usually pretty dumb. It does not do sophisticated stuff like that. Anyway, the JIT can only mutate stuff when the IL code orders it to. It *never* introduces mutation itself because that would be unsafe.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how it might work. Before bigCombinedDelegate is created, what size is simpleCombinedDelegate's _invocationList, and why? If 4, how can it know the last slot is safe to mutate and not already shared with another delegate? If 3, what benefit is there to allocating a new size 4 array and discarding the old size 3 one? I thought the performance benefit was in avoiding an allocation, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Me neither. Look at the source using reflector. The array can contain null values, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing the point here, but garbage collection is by design non-deterministic. Ergo, it is up to the .NET framework to decide when it reclaims memory.

You can run GC.GetTotalMemory in a simple loop and get different figures. Perhaps no surprise as the documentation specifies that the figure returned is an approximation.

Comment: Agree with this answer primarily because the test the OP proposes is too simple to detect much of anything useful. 'Leaked memory' in managed environments usually boils down to poorly designed code (static objects holding references to lists of things.) It's highly unlikely you're going to find any actual bugs in the GC at this point in the game.

Comment: GetTotalMemory does explicit GC. This test is quite reliable. Also notice, that nulling out variables works in all other cases in this test (further evidence that this works as expected).

Comment: I think the point of the OP is that `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` is supposed to force a collection, but after nulling both large delegates and forcing a collection, the memory is still allocated.

Comment: I'm saying that this is likely not a bug in the GC and a contrived example.

Comment: Yes, garbage collection occurs but which generations are collected?

Comment: I believe GC.GetTotalMemory(true) is all generations.

Comment: Also, the figures returned are "an approximation" of "the number of bytes thought to be allocated" according to the specification. Hardly a repeatable test! As you can quickly see by example, the figures returned are often different - even in an empty loop which hardly makes it a suitable candidate for trapping a potential memory leak.